# Command history in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history

Currently I have zsh set up in such a way that command history is shared between all sessions immediately.

Say I have a terminal emulator open with two tabs, each with a zsh session, A1 and A2. If I enter **ls -la** in A1, and then go to A2 and press up arrow key, I will see **ls -la** in the command prompt.

I would like to change it so sessions don't share the command history with each other **although** when you start new session it gets all the previous history from all sessions before it.

Comment: I do that regularly. There's however a lot of questions which still have no satisfactory answer.

Comment: Great question and helpful answers. I thought this was an iTerm2 thing specifically. Hopefully this comment will someone this way if they make the same assumption.

Comment: @Art congrats for the first k. Maybe one could add `oh-my-zsh` as question tag besides `zsh` and `history`..

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've probably got `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` set.

The `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` option, from `man zshoptions`:

> This options works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history lines are added
>   to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as they are entered), rather than waiting
>   until the shell exits.

The option that you want is `APPEND_HISTORY`:

> APPEND_HISTORY 
>   If this is set, zsh sessions will append their history list to the history file, rather
>   than replace it. Thus, multiple parallel zsh sessions will all have the new entries
>   from their history lists added to the history file, in the order that they exit. The
>   file will still be periodically re-written to trim it when the number of lines grows
>   20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also the HIST SAVE BY COPY
>   option).

You can read about these options in the `man zshoptions`, `man zshall` or online [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions).

To set them, in your `~/.zshrc` or similar, you should have:

```
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
```

Be aware that, if you're using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) by default, I believe, `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` is used. I'm not 100% sure which way around things get loaded, but if the `oh-my-zsh` option overrides the one you've set in `~/.zshrc`, you can fiddle with it in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/history.zsh`

Comment: `echo unsetopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY >~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/history.zsh`

Comment: How can iTerm2 be configured to restore the individual history of tabs after a restart (for zsh and oh-my-zsh)?

Comment: I quite like the shared history, but every so often I want to see the history of a single session. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 19):

To add to the accepted answer, if you use `oh-my-zsh`, you probably have `SHARE_HISTORY` option enabled by default.

To achieve separation between running shells + entire history combined in a newly opened terminal, you have to comment or remove the following line:

```
setopt share_history # share command history data
```

from `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/history.zsh`

Comment: In my case, the path of history.zsh file is `~/.antigen/repos/https-COLON--SLASH--SLASH-github.com-SLASH-robbyrussell-SLASH-oh-my-zsh.git/lib/history.zsh`

Comment: Another way to go about it is to put `unsetopt share_history` in your `.zshrc` after `oh-my-zsh` is loaded. Documented [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2537).

Comment: thanks @counterbeing that fixed it for me -- you should make that a separate answer, it's the easiest way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), add:

```sh
unsetopt share_history
```

On your `.zshrc`, **after** oh-my-zsh is loaded (`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`).

[Source](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2537). [Credits](https://superuser.com/questions/410965/command-history-in-zsh#comment1677754_1017151).