# iTerm2 (version 3): Individual history per tab?

Tags: command-line, terminal, iterm2

I’m using iTerm2 (version 3) and like it. But something that it has been doing for a while that's really annoying is that the command history is shared between tabs. E.g., in your first tab, run command `foo` and command `bar`, then go to your second tab and run `say Hello`, and then go back to the first tab; I would like and expect the up arrow to suggest `bar` and then `foo`, but instead it will suggest `say Hello`.

Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Comment: If you are using zsh, append these two lines to `.zshrc` : `unsetopt inc_append_history` and `unsetopt share_history`.

Comment: @harrymc If you made this a full answer, I could accept & award bounty… I ended up finding https://superuser.com/a/412439/60337 which is really my answer. I’m an Oh My Zsh user

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: What about if you're using bash?

Comment: @ben Wilson There’s an answer for that now. Scroll down.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you are using zsh, append these two lines to `~/.zshrc` after line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

```
unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt share_history
```

From
[zshoptions(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) :

> **INC_APPEND_HISTORY**
>
> This options works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history lines
> are added to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as they are
> entered), rather than waiting until the shell exits.
>
> **SHARE_HISTORY**
>
> This option both imports new commands from the history file, and also
> causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file (the
> latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY).

The poster has indicated that this was rather the option he was looking for:

> **APPEND_HISTORY**
>
> If this is set, zsh sessions will append their history list to the
> history file, rather than replace it. Thus, multiple parallel zsh
> sessions will all have the new entries from their history lists added
> to the history file, in the order that they exit.

Comment: someone give this person a raise!

Comment: working for me.

Comment: Make sure you put this ^ after this line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` otherwise, these options are overwritten

Answer (score 16):

Extra info to the perfect answer of harrymc.

This is not Iterm2 but a feature of zsh which gets activated by default if you use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

(see: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/history.zsh)

So put these in your .zshrc file after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` (see harrymc's answer)

```
unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt share_history
```

Comment: **after** `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` <-- That's the key, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can set your HISTFILE environment variable to something unique, but what I do is simply unset it in my .*bashrc* file:

```
export HISTFILE=""
```

but I don't care to keep my history in a file.  By unsetting, history is just kept in memory.

Answer (score 2):

For `Bash` users, just add these two lines into your `~/.bashrc`

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -c;history -r;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Make sure you open a new tab for this to take effect

Comment: Can any bash users confirm or correct the answer here as needed? It looks useful but is sitting at a net vote score of zero, which suggests maybe it doesn’t work. Some clarity would be great

Comment: it consolidates the history from  all tabs and windows.